# Import bacpac containing security policies and temporal-tables with schemabinding

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I've created a `bacpac` backup of my database (both Azure and local with SSMS). Trying to import the `bacpac` to same or another machine (again both Azure and local) the import always fails with this error:

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Meldung 3729, Ebene 16, Status 4, Zeile 1 Cannot ALTER 'SecTable' because it is being referenced by object 'sec_SecTable'. Error SQL72045: Fehler bei der Skriptausführung. Ausgeführtes Skript: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SecTable] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF); ...

SQL-Server versions: 14.0.3223.3 and 15.0.1800.32.

Already tried different versions of SSMS (17,18) and via `SqlPackage.exe` (Visual Studio 19 and SSMS 17/18) to execute the import/export of the `bacpac`.

The smallest DB creation script that will reproduce this problem is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SecTable](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
    [SystemHistoryStart] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [SystemHistoryEnd] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
    [SecValue] [int] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SecTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SystemHistoryStart], [SystemHistoryEnd])
) ON [PRIMARY]
WITH ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[SecTable_History]))
GO

-- Function
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[sf_SchemaBoundTableFunction]
(
    @secValue int
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
RETURN
    SELECT 1 AS Result
GO

-- security policy
CREATE SECURITY POLICY [dbo].[sec_SecTable] 
ADD BLOCK PREDICATE [dbo].[sf_SchemaBoundTableFunction]([SecValue]) ON [dbo].[SecTable] BEFORE DELETE
WITH (STATE = ON, SCHEMABINDING = ON)
GO
```

Any suggestions or workaround how to solve this problem or how to configure the import/export of the `bacpac` without removing the `schemabinding`? Is it maybe a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: No we didn't. We finally dropped the schemabinding.